# Adding a line break in json

Tags: json, liquid, zendesk

Can anyone let me know how can I add a linebreak while creating json. I am trying to update a ticket with a comment in zendesk using api. However, the issue is it needs to be formatted as below:

> The last follow up email has been sent to the customer for the ticket
>   {{ticket.id}}. Please call the customer and add a note to the ticket.
>   Customer details:
>   Name: {{ticket.requester.name}}
>   Phone: {{ticket.requester.phone}}
>
> Thank you

And below is the Json which I am trying to send. If I add a simple enter then I am getting error. I believe for someone who has worked with liquid will be easy.

```
{
  "ticket": {
    "comment": {
      "public": false,
      "body": "The last follow up email has been sent to the customer for the ticket {{ticket.id}}. Please call the customer and add a note to the ticket. Customer details:Name: {{ticket.requester.name}}, Phone: {{ticket.requester.phone}} Thank you"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need a line break after "customer details:"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
   "ticket":{
      "comment":{
         "public":false,
         "body":` The last follow up email has been sent to the customer for the ticket {{ticket.id}}. Please call the customer and add a note to the ticket. 
Customer details:
Name: {{ticket.requester.name}}, 
Phone: {{ticket.requester.phone}} 
Thank you`
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` in places where you need to have line breaks e.g.

```
{
  "ticket": {
    "comment": {
      "public": false,
      "body": "The last follow up email has been sent to the customer for the ticket {{ticket.id}}. Please call the customer and add a note to the ticket.\nCustomer details:\nName: {{ticket.requester.name}},\nPhone: {{ticket.requester.phone}}\n\nThank you"
    }
  }
}
```